# Windows 8.1 suspicious user account keeps getting created

Tags: windows, windows-8, user-accounts, virus

A new user account is automatically created again and again no matter how many times I delete it. It is a random string ("raxxujpxh") that appears as the user name.

Does anyone know what might be causing it or how to close this backdoor into my computer?

Comment: When you say random do you mean its always the same random string "raxxujpxh" or is it a random string that's look simmilair to that example each time?   Is it a user account or an ADMIN account?  Have you checked logs for activity that might give clues?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Press Windows+R key on your keyboard simultaneously.
2. In the window type in control userpasswords2.
3. Now you should be seeing User accounts window.
4. Select the user account that you want to remove and click on remove option.

   ---

If this didn't work, can you tell me if the account's is the same every time?

If so then try  this:

1. Create a new desktop shortcut that points at cmd.exe. Call it Console.
2. Right-click this shortcut, then run it as Administrator.
3. Type the following command and press Enter:
   net user "XXaxxsax" /del
   (replace "XXaxxsax" with the user's account name)

If you also wish to get rid of the user's profile folder, do this:
4. Reboot the machine.
5. Log on as Administrator.
6. Open a Console session as it Step 2 above.
7. Type this command:
    rd /s /q "c:\Users\XXaxxsax"
Note: This method will permanently delete all files and folders in the user's profile folder. They will not be retrievable.

---

Tell me if it didn't work, Okay?

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy.. I'll be trying these solutions now :)